# Arrayformula shows error: Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

Tags: arrays, excel, runtime-error, vba

I know following `FormulaArray` is a long line. But i don't know how to solve this because it shows `Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class`

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

Workbooks.Open (TextBox3.Text)

x = Split(TextBox2.Value, Application.PathSeparator)
y = Split(TextBox3.Value, Application.PathSeparator)

Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Activate

Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("y5").FormulaArray = "=iferror(INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-24])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""DC""),0),10),""-"")"
With Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("y5:y3263")
.FillDown
.Value = .Value
End With
```

If I write the formula without `IFError()' then it works. This is code given below.

```
Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("y5").FormulaArray = "=INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-24])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""DC""),0),10)"
```

But problem with my formula is that it return "#N/A" error when match is not found in the sheet `'[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'`. So that i want add the formula with `IfError()` function. But its not working

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Hello friends, in the same `FormulAarray` i used function `IFNA()`. It works now. But execution was slow. I want to compare 3259 data from File 1 (`Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Sheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate")`) to ~900.000 data in file 2 (`'[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'`). Is there any way to work this formula faster?

Comment: But still my next similar formula is not working. I used `.Replace` method. But again shows same error.

    Dim FormulaPart1 As String
    Dim FormulaPart2 As String
    FormulaPart1 = "=ifna(INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,part2,0),10),""-"")"
    FormulaPart2 = "=MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-25])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""Diverse"")"
    With Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Worksheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("z5")
    .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
    .Replace "part2", FormulaPart2, xlPart
    End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here i have found answer for my problem. I have searched internet and get correct solution with `.Replace` function.

```
Dim FormulaPart1 As String
Dim FormulaPart2 As String
Dim FormulaPart3 As String
Dim origRS As Long

origRS = Application.ReferenceStyle
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(""Part2"",""-"")"
FormulaPart2 = "INDEX('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C1:C10,""Part3"",10)"
FormulaPart3 = "MATCH(1,('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C5=RC[-25])*('[" & y(UBound(y)) & "]Regelung&Partno'!C9=""Diverse""),0)"

With Workbooks(x(UBound(x))).Worksheets("KomponentenohneDuplikate").Range("z5")

.FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
.Replace what:="""Part2""", replacement:=FormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart
.Replace what:="""Part3""", replacement:=FormulaPart3, lookat:=xlPart

End With
Application.ReferenceStyle = origRS
```